# How to define spacing of additional bar in barplot?

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot `y1`, `y0` and their ratio `dy` side by side. `dy` should appear at a small spacing behind the main bars. The (rotated) x-axis ticks should be centered under the three bars that belong together.

I've been messing around with `width` and `space` as well as `at` options for a while but I haven't understood the rationale behind it yet. The best solution so far was to add a new plot for `dy`, but it's still far from ideal, though.

```
barplot(rbind(d$y0, d$y1), beside=TRUE, xaxt="n", col=c("darkgrey", "white")
        # , width=c(1, 1, .2)
        , space=c(0, 2)
        )
barplot(d$dy, add=TRUE, width=.2, space=c(19, 25), col="blue", xaxt="n")
box()
axis(1, at=seq(1:7)*4 - 1.5, labels=2000:2006, las=2)
```

[image]

**How can I do that with base plot? Could anyone explain how to define the parameters?**

***Expected Output***

The expected output should be something like this.

[image]

***Data***

```
d <- structure(list(y0 = c(837.4, 798.6, 817.9, 882.6, 870.3, 857.9, 
776.6), y1 = c(827.1, 790, 807.7, 871.9, 861.8, 849.5, 768.2), 
    dy = c(122.999761165512, 107.688454795893, 124.709622203203, 
    121.232721504646, 97.6674709870162, 97.9135097330686, 108.163790883338
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", 
"5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: How come is `dy` the ratio of `y0` and `y1`? Can you please explain the computation?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sure, `dy` is `(1-(y1 / y0))*1e4`, the `1e4` is for scaling. The plot gets a secondary y-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the extra (blue) bar in the original boxplot to get it to line up right.  I am also adding in a bar with zero height to space the blue bar. In order to make the ticks line up,  save and use the return from the call to boxplot.

```
BP = barplot(rbind(d$y0, d$y1, rep(0,7), d$dy), beside=TRUE, 
    xaxt="n", width=c(1,1,0.4,0.2), space=c(0, 2),
    col=c("darkgrey", "white", "white", "blue"))
box()
axis(1, at=(BP[1,] + BP[2,])/2, labels=2000:2006, las=2)
```

[image: Barplot]

According to the `barplot` documentation,

> If height is a matrix and beside is TRUE, space may be specified by
>   two numbers, where the first is the space between bars in the same
>   group, and the second the space between the groups.

so I used what you had `space=c(0,2)` to allow no space between bars and 2 units between groups.

Regarding the width, I wanted to keep with your original width of 1 for the two main bars and 0.2 for the smaller blue bar. I tried making the zero-height bar be width 0.2, but it seemed too close, so I widened the space bar to 0.4.

Comment: Oh yes, `barplot` has this nice return feature, got confused with ordinary `plot`. The blue bar has not yet a small spacing to the left main bars, though.

Comment: I missed that requirement for spacing the blue bar.  I have edited the answer to include that space.

Comment: Our edits have crossed. Great solution, thanks a lot! How did you get the correct `width` & `space` vectors?

Comment: Will add width & space to answer.

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on that +1

Comment: I have just noticed that the width of the blue bars varies strangely slightly but annoyingly. Can you see that too, or do I have a crease in my optics? Is this a bug?

Comment: I clicked on my picture above to make it larger. The blue bars look straight to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187817/discussion-between-jay-sf-and-g5w).

Comment: Investigation of the follow-up problem revealed that everything gets fine when rendering to PDF.